# Plastic SCM and JIRA setup

Tags: linux, jira, plasticscm

I have set up a new JIRA server to use alongside plasticscm. The windows client in 5.4.16.712 has a nice tab in the preferences to select and setup an issue tracking tool. The linux client though(Where the majority of plasticscm is being used) does not have this. I tried adding the  to the client.conf and moving the Jira dll to the client folder to be used. This seems to have done nothing for the gtkplastic that linux now has.

TLDR:
On Linux plastic client I added

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension AssemblyFile="jiraextension.dll" />
</Extensions>
```

And copied that dll file to the client folder from the client/extensions/jira folder

And added the jiraextension.conf file to the client folder

```
<JiraExtensionConfiguration>
<HttpUrl>**myurl**</HttpUrl>
<User>crychair</User>
<Password>**mypass**</Password>
<ProjectKey>PS</ProjectKey>
<WorkingMode>TaskOnBranch</WorkingMode>
<CustomFieldId>customfield_10000</CustomFieldId>
</JiraExtensionConfiguration>
```

I have also asked this question on the plasticscm forums:
http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/3236-plastic-issue-tracking-missing-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Please, follow the next steps:

Files to configure:

${HOME}/.plastic4/issuetrackers//allrepos/.conf

${HOME}/.plastic4/client.conf

Example of client.conf extra lines:

```
<Extensions>
<Extension AssemblyFile="C:\Users\Miguel\wkspaces\codice-wrk\01nerva\bin\client\extensions\jira\jiraextension.dll" />
</Extensions>
```

The issue tracker .conf files can be generated on windows and then transferred to the target linux machine. if you have any issue, please contact to support at codicesoftware dot com and will be happy to assist you.